# Should we use Scheme syntax highlight for Racket questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, tags, syntax-highlighting

The questions tagged only as [racket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/racket) don't display syntax highlight for the code, for example [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55429628/201359). I believe that by default, they should have the same syntax highlight used for [scheme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scheme), because Racket is a Scheme dialect and it would improve the readability of Racket questions.

Comment: Yes, you should use the Scheme highlight for Racket questions.

Comment: Of course :) . But it's a feature request, it should be enabled automatically by default

Comment: OK, done.  There's no "scheme" language highlighting, so I set it to "lisp".

Comment: Thank you!!! Much appreciated :)