# Should we have syntax highlighting for AutoHotkey questions?

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, tags, syntax-highlighting

This question with AutoHotkey (AHK) code has no code highlighting:

1. *[Why does command not run after SetTimer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55672826/why-does-command-not-run-after-settimer)*

We can set some highlighting by using the `Racket` syntax highlighting, which is also not available on Stack Overflow. But the `scheme` syntax highlighting is, then, we can highlight AHK using the `scheme` syntax highlighting.

Can we symlink tag `ahk` to use the `scheme` syntax highlighting?

Example of `ahk` using `scheme` syntax highlighting:

1. *[How to determine whether a Window is visible on the screen with AHK?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55670223/how-to-determine-whether-a-window-is-visible-on-the-screen-with-ahk)*

References:

1. https://github.com/jneen/rouge
2. https://github.com/google/code-prettify
3. [Should we use Scheme syntax highlight for Racket questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382015/should-we-use-scheme-syntax-highlight-for-racket-questions)

Answer (score 5):

No. AHK scripts are not even remotely similar to Racket or Scheme in syntax. Using a syntax highlighter intended for these languages on AHK scripts is likely to highlight some content incorrectly.