# Add syntax highlighting for AutoHotkey (ahk) code blocks

Tags: feature-request, syntax-highlighting

Currently, [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/) (`ahk`) code blocks are not syntax highlighted, like the following code:

```
#z::
MsgBox The Win-Z hotkey was pressed.
Gosub MySubroutine
return

MySubroutine:
Sleep 1000
return
```

While `highlight.js` [supports it](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md#supported-languages), it's not listed in the [officially supported identifiers by Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/843029).

And quote from [Why isn't my code being highlighted correctly?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/184109/843029):

> Look at the [list of highlight.js supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md#supported-languages). If your language is not on the list, it needs to be created within the highlight.js project before it can be deployed by Stack Exchange.
>
> If a language is already on the list but not used on Stack Exchange, please raise a feature request here on Meta to have it deployed on the network.

Therefore, I'm raising a feature request for it.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/382885/should-we-have-syntax-highlighting-for-autohotkey-questions

Comment: @rene That was before highlight.js, right? Wenfang, I can see AutoHotKey in the [list of supported languages](https://github.com/highlightjs/highlight.js/blob/main/SUPPORTED_LANGUAGES.md) but I'm not sure how to enable it here (or if it's supported). I tried `autohotkey` and `ahk` but both didn't work.

Comment: Moderators have been directed by Stack Exchange to indicate that the *current* response to any and all feature requests to add additional syntax highlighting languages, assuming the language is already supported by highlight.js, but not Stack Exchange, is the same as the [answer to: "Julia syntax highlighting"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/368443/271271) on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: @Makyen You cleaned up some very useful comments, could you please restore them?

Comment: @WenfangDu I'll look through them again, but they all appeared to either have already been incorporated into the question, or to be about "meta meta" things (e.g. the number of close votes or reopen votes at the time the comment was made, finding the question in the reopen queue, how many close votes it takes to close a question, differences in what's displayed per user in the review queues. etc.). In other words, things that were either not about this question or which were about past states of this question which are no longer relevant.

Comment: @WenfangDu I read through the comments again. I didn't see anything that remained relevant to the current state of the question. If there's something specific which you felt should be mentioned, please explain what it was.

Comment: @Makyen You're probably right, they're no longer relevant to the question, but they're useful on their own.

Comment: @Makyen Is there a way to send them to me personally so that it stays clean for newcomers?

Comment: No need to bother mods with that - drop by in chat anytime, and we will gladly recite what you feel is needed :)